# Using windows CMD to list ISCSI drives?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, iscsi

I am trying to list all of the driveletters that are connected by iscsi, but I can't seem to find a way to do this.

I am using this to generate a list of drives to backup using ntbackup on an old 2k3 server, and to skip any iscsi drives.

This is in the interim until we can afford Veeam.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately, at the moment I don't have access to a windows box with admin privilages - The [chkdsk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd637756.aspx) utility __might__ be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky to answer without a iscsi target available to me, but would first look into WMIC.

```
wmic logicaldisk >> C:\List-All-Disks.txt
```

Tell me if you can see any indicator for ISCSI and we can figure out how to skip them.  If you don't see anything, check in here.

`WMIC VOLUME  >> C:\List-All-Volumes.txt`